# What's the difference between "includePath" and "args -I PATH" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VS Code in Linux for C++, I found that there are two files I need to configure: **tasks.json** and **c_cpp_properties.json**.

For tasks.json, there is:

```
"args": [ "-I", "$PATH",]
```

and for c_cpp_properties.json, there is:

```
"configurations": ["includePath": ["$PATH1"], ...]
```

So what's the difference between them? If I need to include a header file, which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **tasks.json** is the one you need to compile/build your C++ application. If you are adding a new header file, you'll *definitely* need to specify the path to that header file in `args`, so that it gets passed to your compiler.

From: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_create-a-build-task

> The `args` array specifies the command-line arguments that will be
>   passed to the compiler that was specified in the previous step. They
>   must appear in the order expected by the compiler.

You *definitely* need to set this properly if you are compiling/building using VS Code.

---

The **c_cpp_properties.json** is mainly used to support the intellisense and auto-completion features of the C++ extension. The `includePath` tells the extension where to find the header files, so that you can do things like "Go to definition" or other code navigation operations.

From: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties

> `includePath` An include path is a folder that contains header files
>   (such as `#include "myHeaderFile.h"`) that are included in a source
>   file. Specify a list of paths for the IntelliSense engine to use while
>   searching for included header files. If a path ends with `/**` the
>   IntelliSense engine will do a recursive search for header files
>   starting from that directory. If on Windows with Visual Studio
>   installed, or if a compiler is specified in the `compilerPath` setting,
>   it is not necessary to list the system include paths in this list.

You can also modify **c_cpp_properties.json** by accessing the **Intellisense Configurations** UI, by accessing the command palette > C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI).

[image]

You can survive without configuring **c_cpp_properties.json** properly. It's not required to compile/build C++ code. But it can be quite helpful when you're writing your code.

Comment: Thanks so much. No wonder I always find a red squiggle but still can run the codes.